# CodeIgniter PHP Apache 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I did a project in CodeIgniter. It's working fine on my localhost, but giving "500 Internal Server Error" on the remote server. This is my `.htaccess` file content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ezgov
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: same error with my codeigniter. hosting company saying problem with my code, but noproblem while on localhost. can't specify one link because each time different link gets 500 error..

Answer (score 38):

Open httpd.conf generally located in Apache installation directory in windows

`/apache/conf/httpd.conf`

and

`/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`

in Unix based systems. httpd.conf is an Apache configuration file which stores various information about the server.

Search for the module `mod_rewrite.so` or (`mod_rewrite.c` in rare cases). mod_rewrite module is developed to rewrite the requested URLs on the fly. Most of the time you will find in commented state.

`#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.*`

Here `#` character represents that it is commented or disabled.

`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.*`

Remove `#` and restart the Apache Http Server using the command `apache -k restart` in windows or `service httpd restart` in unix systems. You also use XAMPP/Wamp UI to restart Apache in windows systems.

Next create `.htaccess` file in root directory where your CodeIgniter project is located and paste following code

```
# index file can be index.php, home.php, default.php etc.
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# condition with escaping special chars
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Next Find CodeIgniter configuration file, generally located in it's configuration directory.

`./application/config/config.php`

Open the file and make `$config['index_page']` value empty. which looks like this

```
/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Index File
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
  | something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
  | variable so that it is blank.
  |
 */
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Now the story is ended. Everything should work fine. You can find more information about httpd.config at [**Apache Module mod_rewrite**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Hope this helps you. Thanks!!

Comment: This solve my problem when I have CI in a sub folder of another website. Thanks man.

Comment: you rocks.I shifted project to same folder, same db, same auth, same url but problem persist, followed you and :)

Comment: Thanks for this. Did all steps except for httpd.conf steps  (as am on a VPS it would have been difficult) and it WORKED.

Answer (score 9):

Posting this, just in case it helps somebody...
Other answers to this question assume that you have access to apache's configuration files. But if you are on a shared hosting platform and do not have access to directories other than the ones where you are supposed to host your files: the trick was to force php to throw all errors even if apache could not.

Open "index.php" that resides in the root folder of your codeigniter installation;

```
/*switch to development environment*/
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');

if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
        {
            case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            /*added line below*/
            ini_set('display_errors', '1');
            break;
......
```

Making the above change immediately started displaying what was wrong with the code and I was able to fix it and get it up and running.

Don't forget to set your codeigniter environment to "production" once you're done fixing it.

Comment: tried this and no errors were displayed on screen. where can I find these errors?

Comment: Check your browser's console and confirm whether it is indeed error 500 or just a blank page.

Comment: I tried your code, The error goes away but the page is blank. Nothing comes up in the console.

Comment: I had a server error before I tried this solution , after I added the  `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` I knew where was the problem which was a syntax error in my constant.php file.

Answer (score 5):

It's likely that the reason is explained in the error_log. Is there an error_log in the root directory of the web site? Is there a logs folder somewhere else? The reason will be detailed in there.

Answer (score 2):

try this out :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

Probably you have problem with your **htaccess** file. It's helped me as well.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error.

I was given different database name, I have changed with following steps:

1. I have created database in server using cpanel
2. I have created a user
3. I have assigned the previously created database to user
4. I changed database settings with username and dbname etc.