# CodeIgniter Server Error

Tags: codeigniter, controller

In my codeigniter application, there's 10 controllers, but 2 of them have a server error, what's the problem?

in my controller:

```
function index($offset='') {
    $this->load->model('branch_model','branch');
    .....
    $limit = 5;
    $data = $this->branch->page($limit, $offset);
    .....
    $this->load->view('branch', array(
        'branch'=>$data
    ));
}
```

If i insert with echo 'hi'; there's nothing that comes up, just SERVER ERROR, what is that?

Comment: can you paste the server error?

Comment: Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://www.**********l.com/admin/tiket/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Comment: [CodeIgniter PHP Apache 500 Internal Server Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674689/codeigniter-php-apache-500-internal-server-error/6676749#6676749)

Comment: increase the log-level by (by changing the environment variable in index.php file to development) then refresh the page...

Comment: Check to make sure you do not have `$config['compress_output']` in `application/config.php` set to `TRUE`

Comment: compress_output = true, nothing happen, same error

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that your controller is extending the CI_Controller class and that your models are extending the CI_Model class?

Comment: yea, controller is CI_Controller and model is CI_Model

Comment: guys, somebody please help me?!

Comment: that was the only thing i've ever done in CI in my entire life that caused a blank page with no error: extending the wrong classes/models. everything else i've ever done resulted in a generic error as long as the index.php file was set to development mode.

are you sure it's not related to your .htaccess file (if there is one) or something else?

Comment: this is my htaccess:

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^arifintravel\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.arifintravel\.com$
RewriteRule ^mail\/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.google\.com\/a\/arifintravel\.com\/ServiceLogin\?service\=mail\&passive\=true\&rm\=false\&continue\=http\:\/\/mail\.google\.com\/a\/arifintravel\.com\/\&ltmpl\=default\&ltmplcache\=2" [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #RewriteBase /

Comment: #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    
    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/img|/js|/css|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>

Comment: solved, there's . in the last array, so in error log message typed "DOUBLE ARROW...." thanks guys