# Codigniter Mod_Rewrite not working in WAMP

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, wamp

I use CodeIgniter on WAMP. 
The Mod_Rewrite Module of Apache is loaded.
My CI project resides at `C:\wamp\www\store` 
I have copied the rewrite rule from Codeigniter URL documentation ([here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html)):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

The link I am trying to open is `localhost/store/city`
It seems to me that the rule never fires. When I try to open the above address, I receive the default 404 of my browser (not CI) and no rewriting seems to have occurred.
If I load `localhost/store/index.php/city` the correct page loads.
Why would my rule not fire?

Comment: [CodeIgniter and Apache .htaccess Configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6676749/782535)

Comment: If .htaccess is at `/store` directory, I guess you have to add a *RewriteBase* directive, like `RewriteBase /store` after *RewriteEngine*, for that to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed this rule in the file:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://test.com
```

As it turned out the the rewrite rules were not firing at all.  The .HTaccess file needed to be moved.
CI placed it in the Application folder. I dragged it out the parent folder, now all works well.
Strange thing.

Answer (score 3):

try change

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

Your method was trying to load the URL from the base

```
localhost/index.php/city
```

Comment: The problem seems to be that the rule does not fire.  As if the regex does not match.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

this will help you for sure :)

Comment: The problem seems to be that the rule does not fire.  As if the regex does not match.

Answer (score 0):

In application/config/config.php you have to set the index page to blank like:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```