# Removing index.php in CodeIgniter resulting 5xx server error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Suppose i have the following URL

subdomain.example.com/myfolder

where "myfolder" is the root folder of my CI installation (where the application folder is located).

I have the following .htaccess (Credits to Fabdrol & ElliotHaughin):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

When ever i try to access my website such as:

```
subdomain.example.com/myfolder/controller/etc...
```

It always returns a 5xx Internal Server error. However if i add

```
subdomain.example.com/myfolder/index.php/controller/etc...
```

It works perfectly. I am pretty sure there is something wrong with my .htaccess i just don't see where the problem is.

Could anyone please help me fix my htaccess? Thx

*** FYI ***
I also tried to change the following line on my config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = ''; // Originally set to index.php
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI' // Originally set to AUTO
```

When i change the:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myfolder
```

It does not return 500 however, it does not display anything at all.

Just to give some information about the structure of myfolder

```
public_html
---|
   |
   |--mysubdomain_folder
   |     |
   |-----|--myfolder (my website where index.php, .htaccess and application folder are).
```

Comment: Look into this : [CodeIgniter PHP Apache 500 Internal Server Error](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6676749/782535)

Comment: @MadanSapkota i tried that but have no luck. The .htaccess configuration works perfectly on my other site (a non-subdomain site).

Comment: where is your httaccess file in web root or in CI root?

Comment: ci root, i put it together along side with index.php file, controller folder and other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: i am sorry mate but it doesn't work. I couldn't even go to subdomain.example.com/mywebsite (This throws an 5xx error).

Answer (score 0):

I think i might have solved it using this configuration:

my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myfolder

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

My config.php file:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

It turns out that since my application (my ci_root) is not in my root (public_html) i need to amend the RewriteBase from "/" to "/path_to_your_application"

And it turns out if you are creating a subdomain called "subdomain" it will create a folder inside your public_html named "subdomain" and you should treat this as the *root* of your subdomain. Hence i set my RewriteBase to "/myfolder" instead of "/my_subdomain_folder/myfolder".

I hope this solution could help others.

Thanks all for the helps and hints.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a ? after index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|humans\.txt|license\.txt|sitemap\.xml|assets)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I also recomend to let view the files but not the directories with:

```
Options -Indexes
```